# How to remove dried hot glue from a closed door?

Tags: wood, adhesive

Ok so in my room someone used hot glue to close off a small passage way to the attic above. I have searched all over the internet for ways to remove the glue, but none of them seem to work. So basically my question is how do i remove dried hot glue from a closed door?

Useful info:
-Both the heat gun and drier method didnt work
-Tried heating up a metal rod with a torch and using that to burn the glue, but that resulted in alot of smoke everytime the rod touch the glue, and gave me too big of a head ache to continue
-there is only about a 1/4cm between the wood

Comment: So to make sure I/we understand, you have a door that was sealed shut to close off the attic, Presuming the adhesive is hot melt glue and you only have a very tight place to work in to break the seal. The tight place being where the face of the door meets the edge of the door stop. If so, it is also safe to presume there is no way to tell if the sealant is applied at the edge of the door where it is bonded to the jamb as well, let alone the door stop? Or is it the other way around? you are working in the gap at the jamb and the door? It may be caulk, how did you determine it is hot melt glue?

Comment: The questions may have gotten a little confusing. My first impression was you were working on the door stop side of the jamb, then it occurred to me that it may be the other side as in if the door was not sealed, it would pull towards you on opening

Comment: I too am confused about where the glue is.

Comment: Rubbing alcohol causes hot glue to let go. This is based on using it on circuit boards. The alcohol seems to seep in between the glue and the circuit board and then the whole glob comes off in one piece.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully cut as much of the glue as possible with a utility knife. With a small pry bar, cats paw, or flat bar gently pry at the gap. If you can, cut some more glue while prying. you may also consider wedging  a paint scraper,( not to be confused with a putty knife) in the gap, then hitting it with a hammer.  At this point you have to weigh the risk of damage to the door opening against maybe burning down the house melting the glue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the angle on this tool to get your cutting edge into the glue between the two pieces of wood and cut through as much glue as possible, then pry the door open once you have most of the glue removed.

Remove the rest of the wood from both surfaces with sand paper then reseal the wood.
[image]